# Shorthand for "sequence of subsets"

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

May I ask does $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\subseteq P (B)$ mean $\{A_n\}$ is a sequence of subsets of $B$? (Here $P(B)$ means the power set of $B$)

p.s. Also, Is there some shorter way to say "$\{A_n\}$
is a sequence of subsets of $B$
"?

Comment: It is a very awkward way of writing $A_n \subset B$.

Comment: Why not instead, "For each $n\in\mathbb{N},\ A_n \subset B.$" ?

Comment: FYI, there is a slight [abuse of notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_notation) in writing $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\subseteq P (B)$ because $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a **sequence** in $P(B),$ not a **subset** of $P(B).$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro What differences are there? I know the sequence is ordered and subset is not.

Comment: @HIH: *What differences are there?* -- The difference is similar to the difference between the **set** $\{1,\,2\}$ and the **ordered pair** $(1,\,2).$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, $x=\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset\mathcal{A}$ can generally be read as $x$ being a sequence in $\mathcal{A}$, i.e., $x_n\in\mathcal{A}$ for each $n\in\mathcal{A}$. In your case, you have $A_n\in\mathcal{P}(B)$ (so $A_n$ is a subset of $B$) for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, making $\{A_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of subsets of $B$.

Comment: Is there some shorter way to say "$\{A_n\}$ is a sequence of subsets of $B$"?

Comment: Not shorter, but a more intuitive could be "$\{A_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}:A_n\subset B,\,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$" (read ''$:$'' as ''such that'')

Comment: Thank you so much!